# Reading the binary logfiles from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, logging, binary

Our mongod process server has a specified `--logpath` paramter, `/var/log/mongodb`.

Inside that directory is the most recent logfile, `mongodb.log` which I can tail just fine to see the latest output. However, all older files are converted to a format like `mongodb.log.YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:XX` (where XX seems to a simple count `01` only in our case).

All these extra files are binary files however, and I can't seem to dig up anywhere how to read them or how to unpack/convert them to text-readable files.

We are using version 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the log files that are generated by mongodb are human readable ; not binary. The most recent file will tend to have the .log extension and all the older files will be suffixed with the timestamp and count as you mentioned. Hence if you are a unix user you can open these files using a text editor by default but you are on windows you will need to specify an extension explicitly i.e add .log or .txt to the filename and you can open it in text editor of your choice to read its contents.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems something must have completely garbled them. I can see bits and pieces of legible data, but the rest is just gibberish. Thanks!

Comment: Did you  find the solution, as in my case also I found it giberish.